# Error: version number does not start with digit

Tags: dpkg, 11.04, adobe-air

i'm installing `Adobe Air` on `Ubuntu v11.04`. The installation process is successful but when I tried to install an air application, errors occurred.

Here's the usual error I've got from the `.appdata/Adobe/AIR/Logs/Install.log`:

```
[airinstall:20544][ERR] Error occurred during rpm install operation; 
beginning rollback:ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false 
eventPhase=2 text=" error: dpkg: error processing /tmp/FlashTmp.FbSCaL/setup.deb
(--install):; parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 2 package
'myapp.74249ff9cb321f1d45f6ea93a89630d1be111ef2.1':; error in Version string
'V1.48.40': version number does not start with digit;
Errors were encountered while processing:; /tmp/FlashTmp.FbSCaL/setup.deb" 
errorID=1]
```

I've followed every instructions on [how to install adobe air on ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu-corner.com/2011/06/how-to-install-adobe-air-on-ubuntu-11-04-x64/) with user `root`. As per research, this has something to do with the version policy of `dpkg` but I don't know how to configure `dpkg` to ignore versioning. How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have downloaded `Adobe Air` from their [download page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/853/cpsid_85304.html).

Comment: changing the version of my `air` app solves the problem BUT the auto-update for my app is affected. I still wanted to force `dpkg` to accept my `version-number`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have successfully installed my `air` app with no `version number does not start with digit` error. What I did was to downgrade my `dpkg-1.16.0` to `dpkg-1.15.8` using the following command:

```
 dpkg --force-downgrade -i /pathofnewdpkg/dpkg_1.15.8.4ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

I have downloaded the older package [here](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/55202069/dpkg_1.15.8.4ubuntu3_i386.deb).

Since the `version-policy` is enforced on the current version of `dpkg`, the `dpkg-1.16.0`, installing an `air` app that violates this versioning policy of `Debian` will really cause an error.

Comment: Well, if that's the case then is fault of the package maintainers to violate a policy.

Comment: This is the link to the amd64 version for ubuntu 12.04: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.15.5.6ubuntu4.10_amd64.deb

Comment: After removing the package run `dpkg --clear-avail` to clean up the faulty entries from `/var/lib/dpkg/available`

Comment: You can also just [edit the version of the package](https://liangsun.org/posts/resolve-error-version-number-does-not-start-with-digit/)

Answer (score 2):

For me on (L)Ubuntu 15.10, it was as simple as changing the version, from "stable" to "1":

```
*****************************************
**** Debian package creation selected ***
*****************************************

This package will be built according to these values: 

0 -  Maintainer: [ root@anon ]
1 -  Summary: [ redis - web interface ]
2 -  Name:    [ redis ]
3 -  Version: [ stable ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
8 -  Source location: [ redis-stable ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ redis ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]

Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue: 3
Enter new version: 
>> 1
```

Comment: can you provide more context of how you got to this screen?

Answer (score -3):

dpkg --force-bad-version -i  
Will work. Just had to do that with mjpg streamer.

Comment: `dpkg` don't have such switch.

Comment: @Braiam [It doesn't anymore.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/deb-reversion.1.html) Maybe there is another way to achieve the same thing now...